# auto increment number within filename

Tags: php, upload, rename, filenames, auto-increment

My users can upload profile pictures, one by one, but as often as they want.

Let's assume user 1 uploads an image, this code will store it to my uploads-folder:

```
<?php

$fileData = pathinfo(basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));

$fileName = 'user_id_#1#_profilepic_#' . uniqid() . '#.' . $fileData['extension'];

$target_path = "uploads/" . $fileName;

while(file_exists($target_path)) {
    $fileName = 'user_id_#1#_profilepic_#' . uniqid() . '#.' . $fileData['extension'];
    $target_path = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "uploads/" . $fileName);
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_path)) {

    echo "The image was successfully uploaded. <a href='index.php'>Add another image</a>";
}
else {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

?>
```

This uniqid() needs to be replaced, because it's a nightmare to find the images later on in the right order.

I want the images - after uploading - to look like this:

```
user_id_#1#_profilepic_#1#.jpg
user_id_#1#_profilepic_#2#.jpg
user_id_#1#_profilepic_#3#.png
user_id_#1#_profilepic_#4#.gif
user_id_#1#_profilepic_#5#.jpg
and so on...
```

How can I do this? I don't have any ideas so far.

Comment: Why not use something like a timestamp instead? `$fileName = 'user_id_#1#_profilepic_#' . time() . '#.' . $fileData['extension'];`

Comment: because i didn't know about that option in the first place, but now i'm wondering how i could possibly read that name out when i want to display the different pictures?
If I have an auto increment number in my filename i can just start with the highest numbers und move to lower numbers on click. But if there is a time involved in the filename instead, that won't work, am i right?

Comment: `$users_files = glob('user_id_#1#_profilepic_#*.*');`

Comment: that gives me back ALL profile pictures of user 1, i guess? but how can i get a specific picture, lets say "the newest" picture, of that collection?

Comment: `sort()` them by name and take the last one?  The same way you would do it if you had 1,2,3 etc...

Comment: makes sense, cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increment by file number in your directory (not recommended if your user can delete his pictures) :

```
$total_files = count(glob("./*",GLOB_BRACE)); // count files in directory
echo $total_files;
```

OR :

use a text file where you record a number.

For exemple :  
You user upload a file :  
Get the current number in the text file -> add +1 and rename the file with this number -> record the new number in the txt file.

The best way should be a unique ID from database record but you maybe not use a DB.

I hope that help you.

Have a nice day !

Comment: thanks, i thought about that, but you already mentioned it: if the user deletes a file the entire number-system will be destroyed with the next upload. That's why i cannot use it..

i read about the text-thingything earlier today, but that means i need to create for every user and every picture type (profile picture, blog picture, post pictures etc.) a new file, right? that doesn't seem to be the smartest way to me, too.

Comment: Maybe you can use the "count(glob(..." system and check if the name is already used with the <a href="http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php">scandir()</a> function.

Comment: Sorry for my previou comment, it's my first time on stackoverflow and I don't know yet how to use the text formatting ^^

Comment: no worries, but your link is not working accurate @x2aces

Comment: but i think I'm going for the database solution. actually, if i use a database, i will save the image on my server with a unique ID, and also i store the name of the file in a database with an auto increment id, and some more attributes like the user id and stuff. So I can get the exact link from the database, and even change that link because they have a unique auto increment ID. nice.

Comment: That is indeed the best solution. Good luck and enjoy your development! :)